# Búsqueda de datos entre hojas de Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo un problema al intentar usar la función `BUSCARV` en `Excel`, donde quiero buscar información de una hoja a otra. Mis hojas se llaman `Formulas` y `Datos`. Por ejemplo, quiero buscar la descripción y ubicación, dependiendo del `SKU` (id) de la hoja `Datos` en este caso el `SKU` `312638`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la hoja `Formulas` ingreso la siguiente formula:

```
=BUSCARV(B3,Datos!B:E,Datos!E:E,FALSO)
```

para traer la descripción de la hoja `Datos`, solo que al ingresar esa fórmula me marca el error `#¡REF!`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no me muestra su descripción. En este caso sería: `Llave golpe acod 12pts 1-3/8`.

¿Qué me faltaría agregar o modificar en mi fórmula para traer los datos correspondientes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `#¡REF!` significa que la referencia que estás dando no existe. El problema está en que estás remplazando el parámetro referente a la columna que deseas obtener por una referencia. Esta sería aproximadamente la fórmula que deseas:

```
=BUSCARV(B3,Datos!$B$2:$E,4,FALSE)
```

Al situar `$B$2:$E` le aclaras que busque en el rango formado desde la posición `B2` hasta la última fila de la columna `E` (si quisieras que buscara hasta una fila específica deberías aclararlo, por ejemplo `$B$2:$E$100`).

En el siguiente parámetro, en vez de una referencia, debes situar un número entero indicando la columna que deseas de tu selección. En este caso debes situar `4` porque de la búsqueda solo te interesa la columna número `4` (la columna `1` corresponde a `B`, la columna `2` a `C`, la `3` a `D` y por último la `4` a `E`)

> **Nota:** En vez de `$B$2:$E`, también podrías situar `B:E` como has situado en la fórmula que has usado, el símbolo `$` solo se sitúa para que el valor se mantenga fijo cuando copies los datos hacia otra celda en vez de que sean relativos a la misma, y el número `2` es para evitar buscar en la fila `1` que está ocupada por los encabezados de la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono muy bien, lo que me faltaba es poner el numero 4 en vez de Datos!E:E, y con eso funciono, Gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado @EdgarRojas.

Comment: una pregunta si quiero obtener la columna Ubicacion como es la columna A seria la 0? @ElChiniNet

Comment: Hola @EdgarRojas, `BUSCARV` buscará por defecto en la primera columna del rango que le proporciones y solo puedes seleccionar los columnas dentro de ese rango. En tu tabla, la columna `UBICACIÓN` se encuentra fuera del rango de búsqueda, por lo tanto, si quieres usar esta función, quizás debas variar tu tabla un poco y situar la columna `SKU` antes de la columna `UBICACIÓN`.

Comment: Si lees [la documentación](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/buscarv-funci%C3%B3n-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) verás que pone _**Sugerencia:** El secreto de BUSCARV es organizar los datos de forma que el valor que busque (fruta) esté a la izquierda del valor devuelto (cantidad) que desea encontrar._

Comment: muchas gracias nuevamente, haré lo posible, gracias!!